# Python Version from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: python-3.x, 32bit-64bit

I have python 3.8 32bit and 3.8 64bit installed. Currently, I'm using virtual studio code, and I can't seem to change the Python interpreter from 32.bit to 64bit. How can I create an environment that specific using 64bit since the default has set it to 32bit, I have no luck to do that.

Please advise, and thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Hi I did look at the doc, I created an environment with 64bit, and activated them with C:\Users\....\Scripts\activate.bat. When I navigate to the environment file and run Python command, it still shows 32bit instead of the 64bit that I created

Comment: How do I ensure that the virtual environment has activated? Because there is no (env) in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I created an environment & specify the python 64bit path using virtualenv.

Comment: you should include some details how you did it if you want this to be an answer that is helpful to others